# how to pre load a read only database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used fastcgi when a process starts up and then executes and serves results to a client. I used to preload a readonly database into memory during the start up and then use that to server results. The advantage being the data gets loaded and prepared only once and is readily available.

How can this be accomplished in ASP.NET technology without using an external database technology like memcached etc?

Comment: Deploy a Windows Service that holds the database in memory.  Provide an API to read the data from that service as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how complicated the database is, but if I needed to do this I would load the database into the [application cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx) as datatables, within the [global.asax](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/) application_startup method.

Comment: Please remove link to Facebook. Use a central place that stays forever (imgur has a agreement with SE to keep the data).

Comment: Since when is additional information not necessary or welcomed?